# Etiquette for asking separated parents for a playdate?

Tags: divorce, friends

My young daughter wants to invite a friend at school over for a playdate whose parents I haven't met. I want to email the other parents to invite them, but in the school directory they have different names and addresses, which suggests they might be separated or divorced but I don't know for sure.

Assuming they are separated, I'm worried it would be insensitive to CC both parents in the email in case they're on bad terms. Alternatively, I'm worried it would be rude to email them separately, or only email one parent.

What is the most appropriate etiquette here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, separated parents will have to learn to deal with situations like this as adults, and so it is entirely reasonable to email them both if that is the information you have.  If they're on bad terms, that's on them to work out, not on you.

If I'm able to see who picks the other child up, I would typically email that person [or just introduce myself in person of course].  That's not always feasible, but it's the easiest way to see - if the parents are separated and the child lives with one during the week, that's what I'd go with.

What I would *not* do, though, is pick one and email them based on anything else.  Making assumptions about which parent is appropriate to email can get you into a situation where either or both parents feel slighted (for example, emailing the mom assuming that children usually live with their moms).

Comment: Terrific answer. "If they're on bad terms, that's on them to work out, not on you." Love this.